# asyncio queue multi producer (sync) single consumer

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

an asyncio program has two task that produce messages which are put on a queue, another task consume the queue.

one producer produce periodic task.
the other producer has to be synced with the consumer, it has to await till its own message have been consumed

```
import asyncio
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig( stream=sys.stdout,format='%(asctime)-5s: %(funcName)-15s: %(message)s',datefmt='%I:%M:%S',level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

async def sync_producer(queue):
    for x in range(5):
        item = f"sync producer{x}"
        logger.info(f"{item} ")
        await queue.put(item)# <= at this point I want to await that the message have been consumed 
    logger.info(f"sync producer finish")

async def periodic_producer(queue):
    x=0
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        item = f"periodic producer {x}"
        logger.info(f"{item} ")
        queue.put_nowait(item)
        x+=1

async def consumer(queue):
    while True:
        item = await queue.get()
        logger.info(f"{item}")
        queue.task_done()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    consumer_task = asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue))
    periodic_producer_task = asyncio.create_task(periodic_producer(queue))
    producer_task = asyncio.create_task(sync_producer(queue))

    await producer_task
    periodic_producer_task.cancel()
    await queue.join()
    consumer_task.cancel()

asyncio.run(main())
```

The example does not work as i want beacause `await queue.put(item)` does'not await `queue task_done()`.
A possible workaround could be to put on the queue `(event,item)` where `event = asyncio.Event()` and then `await event`. Is that a "good" workaraound?

Comment: The producer waiting for a queued item to be processed appears to be contrary to the premise of a queue: that of producing and consuming (processing) being **decoupled** from each other. If `sync_producer` needs to **await** the processing, can't it just call the processing function and not bother with queuing in the first place?

Comment: In my real case the consumer will be a CAN bus instance which publish messages on the Bus. I need many normal producer and one single sync cproducer. I don't know if it will be safe to have more corutines using the same 
 CAN bus instance at the same time

Comment: you cancelled `periodic_producer_task` while it is sleeping.